# Google sign out and return to login page

Tags: swift, google-signin

I want to click the `Sign Out` button on the `ListViewController` to sign out the user, and return to the `SignInViewController`, like below picture.

[image]

In `ListViewController` for the `SignOut` button:

```
@IBAction func didTapSignOut(_ sender: Any) {
    //Sign Out
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    //Go to the `SignInViewController`
    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let desVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignInViewController") as! SignInViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(desVC, animated: true)
}
```

When back to the `SignInViewController`, there's a `back` button, which is directed back to the `ListViewController` on it. It seems like the app still has the cache of the user's data so the user doesn't actually sign out.

[image]

But what I want is to go back to the app's initial state that the user has to sign in again.

**My Storyboard**:
[image]

**How I move from `SignInViewController` to `ListViewController`: in `AppDelegate`**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
              withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let tabbarVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabbarIdentifier") as! UITabBarController
      self.window?.rootViewController?.present(tabbarVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**Solution I've tried**:

```
var window: UIWindow?
@IBAction func didTapSignOut(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    let desVC: UIViewController = SignInViewController()
    if let window = self.window{
        window.rootViewController = desVC
    }
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

but now the view didn't change after I clicked the button.

Comment: Don't push the viewcontroller, just change the rootviewcontroller for a initial state

Comment: How do you move from Siginviewcontroller to listviewcontroller?

Comment: instead of `instantiateViewController` try `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`

Comment: @Dharmesh I tried that, seemed not working

Comment: @RajeshKumarR hi, I've updated that in my post, plz have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In google login you are presenting the tabbar controller from signinViewcontroller. So just dismiss the tabbar controller when logout button is tapped

```
@IBAction func didTapSignOut(_ sender: Any) {
    //Sign Out
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    //Go to the `SignInViewController`
    self.tabBarController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `self.navigationController?.pushViewController` to `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController` (this will have a pop animation)

if you need a push animation, use `self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([desVC])`

UPDATED 1:

If you don't mind having no push/pop animation, you can directly change the window

```
let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: desVC)
let window = UIApplication.shared.window
window.rootViewController = nvc
```

UPDATED 2:

Yea, updating via navigationController would not be proper in your hierarchy. Just change the rootViewController of the window (as stated in Updated 1)

Comment: Hi, I tried the `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)` solution, but now when I clicked the button nothing happened, the view didn't change.

Comment: This could be because the rootViewController is ListViewController. Try using the `setViewControllers` option.


Alternatively, was there any issue raised in the logger? How did you transition from SignInViewController to ListViewController?

Comment: I just added the transition code and storyboard to my post, plz have a look :)

Comment: Just updated my answer to handle your navigation hierarchy

Comment: I tried `let desVC: UIViewController = SignInViewController()`, 
        `let nvc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: desVC)`, 
        `let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow`, 
        `window!.rootViewController = nvc`, 
        `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)`, but didn't work